# Best way to check memory consumption of web page & SPA

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, firebug, performance-testing

In the world of SPA, built with frameworks\library likes JQuery, AngularJS, ExtJs, Lodash & various other JavaScript library, how can I check how much memory each page is consuming? 
I also want to know what are the parameters on which I should measure a page? How can I check how much memory each component\control is consuming in a page?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using chrome developer tools (press F12 in chrome):

You can take a memory consumption snapshot with **Take Heap Snapshot** or record it with **Record Heap Allocations**

[image]